# Restarting the count of runs in rasterbrick in R

Tags: raster, r

I got myself a rasterstack with 6300 layers - which represent 70 winterseasons since 1950 till 2019 (70x90 days). Values range from 0.5 to 1.5 and I am looking for amount of runs of at least 5 days with value greater than 1 (for every grid point). So the output is a rasterlayer and value at every grid point gives me the amount of these runs. I am doing so using this function and it works well:

```
 ff<-function(x){
 y<-x > 1
 n<- ave(y,cumsum(y == 0), FUN = cumsum)
 sum(n >= 5)
 }
 Y<-calc(xxx,ff)
```

However, there is a problem. I dont want runs that overlap between seasons to be detected. It means, that if a run begins on 88th day of a season and ends on 5th day of the following season, it is still detected as run according to my function, because after layer 28.2., 1.12. follows, but those are distinct seasons. So I wanna somehow restart the calculations on those runs every 90 days. I thought about some indices, maybe something like:

```
 indices<-rep(1:70,each=90)
 x1<-stackApply(x, indices, fun = ff)
```

but it doesnt work.

Comment: If you split the stack into each season, did the run count on each of those to create one raster per season-stack, then added those up (cell-wise) you'd get what you want?

Comment: Does it not work because it says "Error in FUN(newX[, i], ...) : unused argument (na.rm = TRUE)"? Add an `na.rm` parameter to `ff` and try again. I think the `stackApply` does the split part of my first suggestion.

Comment: Well, it helped, however, it is not counting properly. It is detecting much more runs of at least 5 then it should. If I dont split the whole raster, the function ff works properly. With this, not. :(

Comment: Make some sample data that you can inspect (eg a 3x3 with 12 layers), then split that into 2 lots of 6 layers and look for runs of 3. You should be able to check that by hand...

Comment: So I did it and there is a problem indeed. For example, I did runs of at least 3 in a row for value 3 and it is doing following: I have values 3,3,3,3,2 and it detects 2 runs.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `ff` function isn't doing what you want it to do.

If I understand correctly, this version of the function should return the number of runs of values over 1 that are of length 3 or more:

```
ff = function(x,...){
y<-x > 1
 n<- ave(y,cumsum(y == 0), FUN = cumsum)
 sum(n >= 3)
}
```

So `ff(c(0,2,2,2,2,2,2,0))` should return 1. But:

```
> ff(c(0,2,2,2,2,2,2,0))
[1] 4
```

I can't unpick what the `ave` and the two `cumsum` calls are doing, I'd write this with `rle`:

```
ff = function(x,...){
  runs = rle(x>1)
  sum(runs$lengths[runs$values] >= 3)
 }
```

The first line uses `rle` to get a list of run lengths and values, then the second line returns the number of runs of `TRUE` values (ie `x>0`) that are 3 or more in length.

Hence:

```
> ff(c(0,2,2,2,2,2,2,0))
[1] 1
```

because of the single long run of 2s, and:

```
> ff(c(0,2,2,2,0,2,2,2,0))
[1] 2
```

because of the two runs separated by the zero. Also:

```
> ff(c(0,2,2,0))
[1] 0
> ff(c(0,0,0,0))
[1] 0
> ff(c(0,0,0,0,0,0))
[1] 0
```

After a thorough testing I think this function is correct. Put this in your `stackApply` and see if it works.

*Always* test your little functions as hard as you can to make sure they are doing what you think they are doing before letting them loose on big examples that are harder to inspect!

Comment: Sorry for not uploading stuff, my function works correctly if I put sum(n == 3) at the end, not sum(n>=3).